# Can I reduce the distance between resources?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I created a PGARK private server and noticed that the resources are few and far between. I might have to walk for a minute or more along the beach to find another bush for berries or fiber.

Is there a server config value that I can set to reduce the distance between resources?

Answer (score 1):

Not experienced with PG ARK, but some information from the ["official" guide](https://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/topic/99062-quickie-procedurally-generated-arks-how-to-guide/).

Increasing the density of a resource in a biome will decrease the distance between instances of that resource, in that biome.

For example raising Jungle Tree Density will decrease the distance between jungle trees.

The only parameter I expect to impact bushes will be Grass Density for various biomes (ex. Jungle Grass Density).

All of this of course requires you to create a new procedurally generated ark.

The alternative would be to increase the gather rate, which would cause each bush to give more fiber and berries.

Answer (score 0):

Resources are statically placed, when a map is designed.  There are options to reduce how far from a building, or person, a resource can respawn, but the resource locations, themselves, will always be in the same location.